# Is there an interpretation for this identity from sum of squares?

Tags: variance, interpretation, sums-of-squares

So yesterday my professor wrote the following on the board:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left( x_i - \bar{X}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2 - \bar{X}^2$$

where $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_j$ (This is just average) and the LHS(left hand side) is just sum of squares(averaged). (Or variance from the mean)

It took me a LONG time to realize that on the right hand side the $\bar{X}$ is NOT inside the summation... but even still I had trouble internalizing this identity. It just seems wrong to get rid of the cross terms...(i.e. $(a^2 + b^2 \neq a^2 + b^2)$)

I can prove this mathematically too, but **I'm wondering if there's just an easy interpretation of this formula that I'm not wrapping my head around**

Here's the mathematical proof in case anyone's interested:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left( x_i - \bar{X}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left( x_i^2 - 2\bar{X}x_i + \bar{X}^2\right) \right) \text{(just squaring everything)}$$

$$= \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ x_i^2 - 2\bar{X}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\bar{X}^2\right)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ x_i^2 - 2\bar{X}n\bar{X} + n\bar{X}^2 \right)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ x_i^2\right) - \bar{X}^2 $$

I can believe the math, but it would be nice to have a deeper, more intuitive understanding of this identity if there even is one.

Comment: For approximately the last 2500 years people have been calling this the *Pythagorean Theorem.*

Comment: @whuber uhhh what???

Comment: @whuber Sorry I feel embarrassed now. Is this the same Pythagoreas as in the right triangles?

Comment: If you add $\bar{X}^2$ to both sides and look at a picture of a right triangle, the connection may become a little clearer.

Comment: @jbowman is one of the lengths of the triangle going to be the sim of all the x_i’s? (Sorry for the poor formatting doing this from my phone with a dead laptop)

Comment: All three of the terms are going to be the lengths of the three sides of the triangle.

Comment: There are many references to the [Pythagorean Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pythagorean+theorem+square*+project*) here on CV.  This really, truly is the ancient theorem in two dimensions: $(x_i-\bar x)$ is one vector and $\bar x(1,1,\ldots, 1)/\sqrt{n}$ is another vector.  Euclid said three points determine a plane; this plane is determined by the origin (the zero vector) and these two vectors.  Because the dot product of these vectors is zero, they are at right angles and the Pythagorean Theorem applies.

Comment: @Okay, so I have come back to this lol. I can definitely see the above case holding IF the vectors are perpendicular to each other. I just can't see why a vector and its average vector are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Oh nvm, I'm so sorry. I just proved they have dot product zero to myself.